# how to select comments for each row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have `events` table which include so many cols besides `Id` PK 
and table `Comments` which includes `text`, `eventId` and `Id` PK . 
how can I select the event information and it's comments in one single sql statement, how to use it and how it should look like !?

Note that EventId(Comments) = Id(events)

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to use it'? Do you have an application that uses this data? What kind of application? What programming language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this should do it...

```
SELECT * FROM events
INNER JOIN comments on comments.eventid = events.id
```

If you dont need all columns it is good practice to select only the columns you realy need.

```
SELECT Id, eventId FROM events
INNER JOIN comments on comments.eventid = events.id
```

To Extract it in your C# code you might do it the `System.Data` style:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Put your ConnectionString here"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("My SQL from Above", connection))
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
         adapter.Fill(table);
         // now you can do here what ever you like with the table...

         foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
         {
            if (row.IsNull("Text") == false)
               Console.WriteLine(row["Text"].ToString());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to know how to use and extract it (every event has a lot of comments)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following statement:

```
SELECT e.Id, c.Id, c.text
FROM events e
INNER JOIN Comments c ON e.Id = c.EventId
```